# How to loop through rows in dataframe from one specific value until another in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, loops

I have a following dataframe:

| Time | Tab | User | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27.10.2021 15:58:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Tab Alpha of type PARTSTUDIO opened by User A |
| 27.10.2021 15:59:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature |
| 27.10.2021 15:59:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Cancel Operation |
| 27.10.2021 15:59:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Tab Alpha of type PARTSTUDIO opened by User B |
| 27.10.2021 15:59:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature |
| 27.10.2021 16:03:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Cancel Operation |
| 27.10.2021 16:03:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Add assembly feature |
| 27.10.2021 16:03:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Tab Alpha of type PARTSTUDIO closed by User A |
| 27.10.2021 16:03:00 | Tab Beta | UserA@gmail.com | Tab Beta of type PARTSTUDIO opened by User A |
| 27.10.2021 16:15:00 | Tab Beta | UserA@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature |
| 27.10.2021 16:15:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature |
| 27.10.2021 16:15:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Tab Alpha of type PARTSTUDIO closed by User B |
| 27.10.2021 16:17:00 | Tab Beta | UserA@gmail.com | Add assembly feature |
| 27.10.2021 16:17:00 | Tab Beta | UserC@gmail.com | Tab Beta of type ASSEMBLY opened by User C |
| 27.10.2021 16:17:00 | Tab Beta | UserC@gmail.com | Add assembly feature |
| 27.10.2021 16:17:00 | Tab Delta | UserB@gmail.com | Tab Delta of type PARTSTUDIO opened by User B |
| 27.10.2021 16:54:00 | Tab Delta | UserB@gmail.com | Add assembly feature |
| 27.10.2021 16:55:00 | Tab Beta | UserA@gmail.com | Tab Beta of type PARTSTUDIO closed by User A |
| 27.10.2021 16:55:00 | Tab Delta | UserB@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature |
| 27.10.2021 16:55:00 | Tab Delta | UserB@gmail.com | Tab Delta of type PARTSTUDIO closed by User B |
| 27.10.2021 16:59:00 | Tab Delta | UserC@gmail.com | Add assembly feature |

How to loop through rows in dataframe based on a condition in the "Descripiton" column? The condition is to extract said values (Tab names) between values "Tab 'Tab_name' of type ... **opened** by User B" and "Tab 'Tab_name' of type ... **closed** by User B" to "User B" column.

Expected output:

| Time | Tab | User | Description | UserB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27.10.2021 15:58:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Tab Alpha of type PARTSTUDIO opened by User A |  |
| 27.10.2021 15:59:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature |  |
| 27.10.2021 15:59:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Cancel Operation |  |
| 27.10.2021 15:59:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Tab Alpha of type PARTSTUDIO opened by User B |  |
| 27.10.2021 15:59:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature | Tab Alpha |
| 27.10.2021 16:03:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Cancel Operation | Tab Alpha |
| 27.10.2021 16:03:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Add assembly feature | Tab Alpha |
| 27.10.2021 16:03:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Tab Alpha of type PARTSTUDIO closed by User A | Tab Alpha |
| 27.10.2021 16:03:00 | Tab Beta | UserA@gmail.com | Tab Beta of type PARTSTUDIO opened by User A | Tab Alpha |
| 27.10.2021 16:15:00 | Tab Beta | UserA@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature | Tab Alpha |
| 27.10.2021 16:15:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature | Tab Alpha |
| 27.10.2021 16:15:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Tab Alpha of type PARTSTUDIO closed by User B |  |
| 27.10.2021 16:17:00 | Tab Beta | UserA@gmail.com | Add assembly feature |  |
| 27.10.2021 16:17:00 | Tab Beta | UserC@gmail.com | Tab Beta of type ASSEMBLY opened by User C |  |
| 27.10.2021 16:17:00 | Tab Beta | UserC@gmail.com | Add assembly feature |  |
| 27.10.2021 16:17:00 | Tab Delta | UserB@gmail.com | Tab Delta of type PARTSTUDIO opened by User B |  |
| 27.10.2021 16:54:00 | Tab Delta | UserB@gmail.com | Add assembly feature | Tab Delta |
| 27.10.2021 16:55:00 | Tab Beta | UserA@gmail.com | Tab Beta of type PARTSTUDIO closed by User A | Tab Delta |
| 27.10.2021 16:55:00 | Tab Delta | UserB@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature | Tab Delta |
| 27.10.2021 16:55:00 | Tab Delta | UserB@gmail.com | Tab Delta of type PARTSTUDIO closed by User B |  |
| 27.10.2021 16:59:00 | Tab Beta | UserC@gmail.com | Add assembly feature |  |

Here is my try:

```
df.insert(4, 'User B', '0')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Description'].find('opened by User B') != -1:
        tab = row['Description'].rpartition(' of type')[0]

    if row['Description'].find('closed by User B') == -1:
        df.at[index, 'User B'] = tab
```

Current code extracts tab name from each row where "Description" column does not contain "closed by User B". It should extract only from rows in range specified earlier in the question - between rows where value in "Description" column == "...opened by User B" and "...closed by User B".
I'm aware that df.iterrows is not recommended, however I can't seem to find another way.

Comment: Row 9 and 10 in your output should be "Tab Beta"

Comment: No, output is correct. The code should extract each row (regardless of which user performed the action) between values "...opened by User B" and "...closed by User B", as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```py
df["User B"] = df["Description"].str.contains("opened by User B").shift()
df["User B"] += df["Description"].str.contains("closed by User B") * -1

df["tmp"] = (
    df["Description"]
    .str.extract("(Tab .*?) of type .* opened by User B")
    .ffill()
)

df["User B"] = np.where(df["User B"].fillna(0).cumsum(), df["tmp"], "")
df = df.drop(columns="tmp")

print(df.to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | Time | Tab | User | Description | User B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 27.10.2021 15:58:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Tab Alpha of type PARTSTUDIO opened by User A |  |
| 1 | 27.10.2021 15:59:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature |  |
| 2 | 27.10.2021 15:59:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Cancel Operation |  |
| 3 | 27.10.2021 15:59:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Tab Alpha of type PARTSTUDIO opened by User B |  |
| 4 | 27.10.2021 15:59:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature | Tab Alpha |
| 5 | 27.10.2021 16:03:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Cancel Operation | Tab Alpha |
| 6 | 27.10.2021 16:03:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Add assembly feature | Tab Alpha |
| 7 | 27.10.2021 16:03:00 | Tab Alpha | UserA@gmail.com | Tab Alpha of type PARTSTUDIO closed by User A | Tab Alpha |
| 8 | 27.10.2021 16:03:00 | Tab Beta | UserA@gmail.com | Tab Beta of type PARTSTUDIO opened by User A | Tab Alpha |
| 9 | 27.10.2021 16:15:00 | Tab Beta | UserA@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature | Tab Alpha |
| 10 | 27.10.2021 16:15:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature | Tab Alpha |
| 11 | 27.10.2021 16:15:00 | Tab Alpha | UserB@gmail.com | Tab Alpha of type PARTSTUDIO closed by User B |  |
| 12 | 27.10.2021 16:17:00 | Tab Beta | UserA@gmail.com | Add assembly feature |  |
| 13 | 27.10.2021 16:17:00 | Tab Beta | UserC@gmail.com | Tab Beta of type ASSEMBLY opened by User C |  |
| 14 | 27.10.2021 16:17:00 | Tab Beta | UserC@gmail.com | Add assembly feature |  |
| 15 | 27.10.2021 16:17:00 | Tab Delta | UserB@gmail.com | Tab Delta of type PARTSTUDIO opened by User B |  |
| 16 | 27.10.2021 16:54:00 | Tab Delta | UserB@gmail.com | Add assembly feature | Tab Delta |
| 17 | 27.10.2021 16:55:00 | Tab Beta | UserA@gmail.com | Tab Beta of type PARTSTUDIO closed by User A | Tab Delta |
| 18 | 27.10.2021 16:55:00 | Tab Delta | UserB@gmail.com | Start edit of part studio feature | Tab Delta |
| 19 | 27.10.2021 16:55:00 | Tab Delta | UserB@gmail.com | Tab Delta of type PARTSTUDIO closed by User B |  |
| 20 | 27.10.2021 16:59:00 | Tab Delta | UserC@gmail.com | Add assembly feature |  |

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try finding all "opened" and "closed" descriptions and selecting slicing between them:

```
opens = df["Description"].str.contains(".*Tab.*of type.*opened by User B")
closes = df["Description"].str.contains(".*Tab.*of type.*closed by User B")

df["UserB"] = df["Tab"].where((opens.cumsum().shift().fillna(0)-closes.cumsum()).astype(bool))

>>> df
                   Time  ...      UserB
0   27.10.2021 15:58:00  ...        NaN
1   27.10.2021 15:59:00  ...        NaN
2   27.10.2021 15:59:00  ...        NaN
3   27.10.2021 15:59:00  ...        NaN
4   27.10.2021 15:59:00  ...  Tab Alpha
5   27.10.2021 16:03:00  ...  Tab Alpha
6   27.10.2021 16:03:00  ...  Tab Alpha
7   27.10.2021 16:03:00  ...  Tab Alpha
8   27.10.2021 16:03:00  ...   Tab Beta
9   27.10.2021 16:15:00  ...   Tab Beta
10  27.10.2021 16:15:00  ...  Tab Alpha
11  27.10.2021 16:15:00  ...        NaN
12  27.10.2021 16:17:00  ...        NaN
13  27.10.2021 16:17:00  ...        NaN
14  27.10.2021 16:17:00  ...        NaN
15  27.10.2021 16:17:00  ...        NaN
16  27.10.2021 16:54:00  ...  Tab Delta
17  27.10.2021 16:55:00  ...   Tab Beta
18  27.10.2021 16:55:00  ...  Tab Delta
19  27.10.2021 16:55:00  ...        NaN
20  27.10.2021 16:59:00  ...        NaN

[21 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, this does not do what I had in mind. It might be helpful to someone else tho